# How to get the dictionary key or the set element that is equal to a given object?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, set, equality

Given a dictionary `d` in Python and an object `x`, is there an efficient way to look up the key `k` in `d` that is equal to `x`?

A similar question can be asked about sets in Python: given a set `s` and an object `x`, is there an efficient way to get the element `e` of `s` that is equal to `x`?

The purpose is to avoid keeping in memory duplicate immutable objects.

If keys and elements in question are strings, then, I suppose, some workaround can be found with interning ([`sys.intern`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.intern)), but is there a general solution for arbitrary immutable hashable objects?

As a use case, consider working with an implicit graph where vertices are hashable immutable data structures (maybe just tuples of integers), which are used as dictionary keys to keep some associated metadata. If some vertex is generated twice in a graph traversal and needs to be stored elsewhere, it is reasonable to look up the already used copy and store it twice, rather than store a new copy.  A more concrete example is saving memory in the A* shortest-path algorithm applied to solving the 15-puzzle.

Answer (score -2):

Your question is closely related to the concept of [mutable and immutable objects](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html). The exact answer to your question is also implementation specific. I’ll answer it for CPython, but keep in mind that other implementations have different behaviour.

In CPython, once an immutable object is created (assigned or used), it is created in memory. Every next immutable object with the same value points to the same object(!). You can check this by using the `id` function (which, in CPython is the memory address of the object).

For example:

```python
a = 5  # int's are immutable
d = {5: "five", 8: "eight"}
k = 5

# a and k have the same id; they point to the same object!
print(f"id(a) = {id(a)}") 
print(f"id(k) = {id(k)}")
print(a in d)  # the key a is in dict d
print(d[a])  # the value for key a in dict d

a = (5, )  # tuples are also immutable
d = {(5,): "five", (8,): "eight"}
k = (5, )

# a and k have the same id; they point to the same object!
print(f"id(a) = {id(a)}") 
print(f"id(k) = {id(k)}")
print(a in d)  # the key a is in dict d
print(d[a])  # the value for key a in dict d
```

Even if I assign a constructed or calculated immutable object to a variable, it is the same object (id) as another variable with the same value.

```python
a1 = 3.14
b1 = 'kgvjkdfsjl'
c1 = (63474236728,)
d1 = 1e10
a2 = 3 + 0.14
b2 = 'kgvj' +'kdfsjl'
c2 = (63474236728,)
d2 = 1e9 * 10

print(all([a1 == a2, b1 == b2, c1 == c2, d1 == d2]))  # gives True: the values are all equal
print(all([a1 is a2, b1 is b2, c1 is c2, d1 is d2]))  # gives True: the identities are all equal
```

Back to your questions:

> is there an efficient way to look up the key in d that is equal to k?

You don’t have to do that. CPython takes care of this for you. The same is true for immutable objects in sets.

> is there a general solution for arbitrary immutable hashable objects?

Be aware that immutable objects can have hash values too! By default all built-in immutable objects have hashes, while mutable objects don’t, but users can define classes that have their own hash functions. Thereby creating mutable and hashable objects.

Comment: What you claim is false: `x = 1000; y = 1000; x is y` returns `False`. I believe I have CPython.

Comment: "Every next immutable object with the same value points to the same object(!)" is simply untrue. There's some attempt at interning strings and small integers, but non-trivial uses will often bypass those cases.

Comment: @Alexey. The predefined ints go out to 256 or 128 or so.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, see here: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong

Comment: To all the downvoters: please explain [this behaviour](https://tio.run/##bc7RCoMgFMbxe5/iwC6sFSM1arvoYSzdsqS1smBP71RqxNjdnwPfjzO@TfscmLWcQAXsQnJU@8L9Y@16cZ87jVHjL1HB8jKnrCjpNY2R8DciSYY49UtIIAtruq8xJPgr0D8CDcINzuAUNE5qMFHk/6iA0xTqULWrJlTjSoQSNI4BTmBaCSvXi5yBTxK41iBfC9cHS8275WqzXG2Wq6OlhByMMurXs/YD): when the values of these immutable objects are equal, also their identities are equal.

Comment: @agtoever, sorry, i do not see the point of discussing this behavior here, as it is somewhat offtopic. If you ask a question about it and leave a link here, i will probably comment. Or we may talk in chat, but i do not have much time right now.

Comment: @Alexey in your first comment, you state that my claim is false, [but your code does not proof that in TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v0LBVsHQwMDAWqESziooyswr0ahQyCxWqNT8/x8A).

Comment: @agtoever, did you try it on your machine? I showed the result on mine. Moreover, the mode of functioning you suggest is clearly unfeasible for arbitrary immutable data structures.

Comment: It returns `True` (as can be shown by clicking the link), not `False` (as you state)...

Comment: @agtoever, does it return `True` on your machine?